# Describing $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(m))$ as gluing of affine charts

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

How can we describe $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(m))$ as a gluing of affine charts? I'm having trouble with this problem, perhaps because I don't understand the geometry of what's going on particularly well. I'm also meant to do the same for $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-m))$. Is anyone willing to walk me through it?

Comment: Maybe you can look at [this question][1] for $m=1$.


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514060/birationality-and-isomorphism-of-hirzebruch-surfaces/514355#514355

Comment: I don't really understand the connection. Is there any way that you can walk me through this argument in particular? Since there are two cases, perhaps you could include a description of the first, and I could check my understanding by supplying a description of the second?